# what are the steps to download dotnetnuke(dnn) community edition

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-6

can any one please help me how to download dotnetnuke(dnn) community edition.?

Please Help Me how to download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from [CodePlex](https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to dnnsoftware.com and follow the links to the install package.  You will also find instructions.